# Are there any .Net ports of the MonsterID gravatar generation

Tags: .net, gravatar

Does anyone know of a .Net port for the auto generated gravatar [MonsterIDs](http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_monsterid/) icons? I'd like to generate monsters locally in my .Net app.